# Performance testing bottneck microsercice

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, thrift, latency

I am using jmeter to load test my APi server(running on tomcat) which inturn calls a micrroservicr using thrift.(20k requests/min)

I am using new relic for monitoring . I have observed that a an abnormally high time is spent when API calls the microservice(ranging from 10-15seconds).So I observed the microservice over the same duration. The response time was almost negligible.(10-12 milliseconds)

So, I suspected probably API is queueing up the responses because it is unable to accept the rate at which its receiving response from the microservice.To address the same I doubled `Xmx` and `Xms` value of my API java application.

Still am observing the same , what could be the bottleneck which I am missing out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your API running on Tomcat has enough headroom in terms of CPU, Ram, Network, Disk, etc. as it might be slowing the things down. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for this
2. Make sure that Tomcat itself is configured for high loads as the threads might be queuing up on [Tomcat HTTP Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html), i.e. if threads in executor are less than the number of connections you establish - the requests will be queuing up even before reaching your API
3. Re-run your test using profiler tools telemetry, i.e. set up [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/) monitoring - this way you will learn where your API spends the most of time and what is the underlying reason

Comment: My API server is running on tomcat but API talks to microservice using thrift client .. I don't think http tuning would help since my latency is observed during communication of API and microservice

Comment: Then check your Thrift server as well. Also pay attention to how does API and Thrift communicate as it might be a transport-level problem